# How to plot graph for accelerometer sensor values in Android?

Tags: android

I am quite new to Graphs in android, How can I plot a Graph for Accelerometer sensor values which is Dynamically running.

Comment: Use some predefined libraries. There are many open source libraries. Google them, you'll find answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a library like AndroidPlot or AChartEngine. 
They are both licensed under the apache license

AndroidPlot: http://androidplot.com/

AChartEngine: http://www.achartengine.org/